# Display permanent link in search engines

Tags: html, seo

I am doing pretty basic thing here.

Showing some posts on a page. Each post is inside a div and has an anchor tag showing its permanent url

for example

```
  <div>
    <a href='permanent_link_url'>permalink </a>
    Summary of the Post
  </div>
```

Now when I am trying to search for a post on popular search engines, they are not displaying the permanent link that I have included in the div, so rather than redirecting me to the permanent link of the post, its redirecting me to the home page of the website

Any suggestions on what should be done here to overcome this issue

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look at the [canonical link](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/139394?hl=en) standard to help you out here. I'm assuming the permalink actually works as a URL and that it is on the same website.

So for your example, I would include some HTML in the `<head>` section of the page that has:

```
<link rel="canonical" href="the_permanent_link"/>
```

so that you can instruct the search engines that this is in fact the best link to the content in question. Where possible, you should also correct your "old" links to the canonical link. You may also want to send [sitemaps](http://sitemaps.org) to the popular browsers as a best practice.